# djangoのモデルで、複数の列の値の組を、複数指定して検索する方法

Tags: python, sql, django, sqlite

djangoのモデルを利用して、以下のようなクエリーをかけたいのですが、
モデルクラスで実現可能でしょうか？

```
select
    *
from
    table t
where
    (t.col1, t.col2) in (
        ("hoge", "fuga"),
        ("foo", "bar")
    )
```

https://qiita.com/lithtle/items/4517785c67843f601443より引用

私は、以下でもよいかと思ったのですが、

```
query_set = app_model.SampleModel.objects.filter(col1__in=['hoge', 'foo'], col2__in=['fuga', 'bar'])
```

(t.col1, t.col2)が("hoge", "bar")のレコードが存在した場合、正しくない結果が戻ることが分かりました。
正しい方法を教えていただけないでしょうか。

Comment: 自PCで確認したところ、sqlite3で、複数列を指定したin句を含むSQLを実行したところ、以下のエラーが発生しました。サポートされていないのかもしれません。

Comment: エラーメッセージ：OperationalError: row value misused

Comment: 実行したSQL：cursor.execute('SELECT id, date FROM xxxx_table WHERE (id, date) in ( ("xxxx", "2021-05-18 15:00:00"), ("yyyy", "2021-05-19 15:00:00") )')

Answer (score 0):

複合キーとなる列を、'_'で連結したものを、主キーとして持たせることで、
疑似的に複数の列でin句を利用できるようにしました。
（複合キーの文字列長が固定としました）
データの挿入時などに、主キーを自力で設定する必要がありますが、
回避策のひとつとして記録に残します。

```
from django.db import models
class TableModel(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=5)
    col1 = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    col2 = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'table'

model = TableModel(id='aa_xx', col1='aa', col2='xx')
model.save()

delete_list = [ 'aa_xx', 'bb_yy' ]
TableModel.objects.filter(id__in=delete_list).delete()
```

Comment: よりよい方法ありましたら、教えていただけないでしょうか。